# Method to re-arrange rows every minute

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want my google-sheet to put my rows in a cycle.In this cycle, each row goes to the top of the rows for a specified time.Then, it becomes second and another one becomes the first row.If I have 60 rows , I want every one of them to be the first row for one minute.

How would I do that ?

Comment: oh right :) ok good though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code to do so ...in my code , the row starts at A and ends at E .. and you should put time-driven trigger to implement the function.

```
function Update() {
  var returnSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  returnSheet.insertRowAfter(1);
  var rowCount = returnSheet.getLastRow();
  var rrCell = 'A' + rowCount;
  var rrCell2 = 'E' + rowCount;
  returnSheet.getRange(rrCell+':'+rrCell2).moveTo(returnSheet.getRange("A2:E2"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Script Flow:

- Start with second row(say, current row) or get current row from properties.
- Use `sheet.moveRow(sheet.getRange('currentRow:currentRow'),1)` to move the current row to first.
- Increment current row by 1 and store it properties.
- Use a time-driven trigger to repeat this script every minute.

#### References:

- [Sheet#moveRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moveRows(Range,Integer))
- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [Time driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)